# How to get source code of Input url inside div?

Tags: javascript, html

Here is my HTML and I want to show source code of url with (view-source+url) inside class `.source-html` from input when I click on button?

```js
const input = document.querySelector("#input");
const button = document.querySelector(".view");

button.addEventListener("click", (x) => {
  const url = input.value;
  const sourceUrl = "view-source:" + url;
  //Some code that show source of url inside div

});
```

```html
<input id="input" type="text" />
<button type="button" class="view">View Source</button>

<div class="source-html"></div>
```

If possible, help me.

Comment: Are you trying to get the value of the input or the text inside div.source-html?

Comment: What i want is if i enter https://www.google.com in the input and click on the button then show the source code of the url in the div.

Comment: This should do the trick `const input = document.querySelector("#input");
const button = document.querySelector(".view");
const output = document.getElementsByClassName("source-html")[0];

button.addEventListener("click", async (x) => {
  const url = input.value;
  
  await fetch(url)
  .then((response) => response.text())
  .then((data) => {
     output = data;
  });

});
`

Answer (score 0):

The modern browsers not allowed to load local source of the website. This is due to security policies. If you load other websites source into your site, then there is a chance to load malicious scripts.

Still if you try to load the view-source then you may encounter with "**CORS** error" or "**Not allowed to load local resource**: view-source:"

You can still use the below code to view the source of same origin sites.

```
const input = document.querySelector("#input");
const button = document.querySelector(".view");

button.addEventListener("click", (x) => {
  const url = input.value;

  //view source of same origin
    $.ajax({
        url: url,
        success: function(x){
            console.log(x);
        }
    })
});
```